# Why do custom build configurations fail to load source location data

Tags: visual-studio, debug-symbols, buildconfiguration, nunit-3.0

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.  In my project, I have NUnit tests covering a variety of projects.  The NUnit tests are version 3.0.1, and the test runner is version 3.0.8.0.  I have the usual build configurations (`Debug` and `Release`) and an additional one of my own creation: `Stress`.  When I build in `Debug` or `Release`, everything works fine.  However, when I build in `Stress`, I get the following message in my test output build window:

```
Unable to create DiaSession for D:\Code\EncounterGen\Tests\Integration\Bootstrap\bin\Stress\EncounterGen.Tests.Integration.Bootstrap.dll
No source location data will be available for this assembly.
```

This only occurs in my custom build configuration.  When I run the tests, all of the normal links are broken - double-clicking on a test does not take you to that method in the test class, the stack trace in the test failure will not take you to the relevant line, etc.  I am compiling all projects in the `Stress` build configuration.  I am not sure what the problem is.

[Other research](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/xQ3uP6fqmaA) suggests that the DiaSession failure is from NUnit, indicating that it can't load source code - which would explain the symptoms, but not the cause.  The only articles I could find discussing it only mentioned what it did, nothing regarding problems or errors of why it would not load correctly for NUnit.

This used to be working - I am not sure when this problem started occurring exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that my `Stress` build configuration was not set to generate .pdp files.  I had to go into each project, go to the Build tab, click Advanced while `Stress` was the selected build, and change `Debug info` from `none` to `full`.  I suspect that when I created this build for the solution, I copied settings from `Release` instead of `Debug`, which is why this occurred.